# Processing Draw Program

Tags: drawing, processing

I was making a basic paint/draw program in processing where the Left click would draw a point and a Right click would draw a background colored rectangle to "erase". The thing is that when I start erasing it wont let me go back to drawing. Also i would like to make the dots draw faster so it looks more like a line rather than a dotted line. Thanks!
Here is the code:

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(#C4C4C4);
}

void draw() {
  frameRate(60);
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    fill(#030303);
    point(mouseX, mouseY);
  }

  else if(mouseButton == RIGHT){
    fill(#C4C4C4);
    noStroke();
    rect(mouseX-15, mouseY-15, 30, 30);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you call `noStroke()` when the user presses the right button, but you never set the stroke back when the user presses the left button. The `point()` function uses the stroke color, not the fill color, so you have to reset it. This works:

```
void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  background(#C4C4C4);
}

void draw() {

  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    stroke(#030303);
    point(mouseX, mouseY);
  }

  else if(mouseButton == RIGHT){
    fill(#C4C4C4);
    noStroke();
    rect(mouseX-15, mouseY-15, 30, 30);
  }
}
```

As for drawing lines instead of a point, you can use the `pmouseX` and `pmouseY` variables (which hold the previous position of the mouse) to draw a line. Specifically, change this:

```
point(mouseX, mouseY);
```

To this:

```
line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
```